# bash how to replace/delete beginning of line followed by white space

Tags: bash, text, sed

I'm parsing long texts and part of the byproduct of previous commands is:
1) lines with only one white space
2) line that have one white space followed by a sentence.

How do I get rid of them?

I have tried the following:

```
tr -s [:space:] |sed -r 's/\^ /\^/g' > output.txt
```

and the following

```
tr -s [:space:] |sed -r 's/\n //g' > output.txt
```

and the following

```
sed 's/\([.!?]\)[[:space:]]*/\1\n/g' file > output.txt
```

No success.

Sample Input (underlines represent spaces for better visual understanding)

```
_Sir_William_Blackstone,
_
_Commentaries_on_the
```

Sample output

```
Sir_William_Blackstone,
Commentaries_on_the
```

Comment: I don't understand your description. Are you trying to get rid of just whitespace at the beginning of lines, or something else?

Comment: Correct, I'm trying to get ride of that single white space at the beginning of the sentence. I am assuming this will also have me clean up blank lines that only have only 1 blank space (left by tr -s [:space:] ).

Comment: At the beginning of a sentence, or the beginning of a line? If it's at the beginning of a sentence, how is a sentence defined? Also, cleaning up blank lines will generally be a separate thing.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Done. Added sample input and output for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `sed`.

```
sed -E '/^\s*$/d; s/^\s*//;' < in > out
```

This deletes lines with only whitespace, and strips whitespace off the beginning of other lines.

c.f. https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html

There are refinements, but this is the general idea.

Comment: sed 's/^ //'   this alone works (I tested) on also removing lines with only one space (left over from tr -s [:space:])since there is nothing left for the line it gets deleted. Thanks

Comment: @HenryM Empty lines are *not* automatically deleted (unless there's something else in the pipeline that's doing it?).

Comment: This is the code: tr -s [:space:] < input.txt | sed 's/^ //'  > output.txt. Based on my results and outcome from my samples it works. tr -s only leaves behind single white spaces, which can be annoying when it is the only thing in a line. Your code deletes that last white space on the line, and it dispersers. If a line doesn't have anything in it, how can I exist...am I missing something?

Comment: Why use both `sed` AND `tr` when `sed` will do both simple functions with just one process?

Comment: tr -s [:space:] gets rid of also many consecutive white spaces bracketed by text. plus is just so easy to use

Comment: If you want consecutive spaces removed, say so. Clear specs are important. Edited the post. What you're doing works, and is fine, but it's always good to add new tricks to the bag, and eventually performance will matter.

Comment: @HenryM A line with nothing on it can certainly exist; in the unix file format, it's just a newline character (end-of-line marker) immediately followed by another newline. Try `printf '%s\n' one two three | sed 's/two//'` -- the `printf` prints three lines, `sed` removes the content of the second, but the output is still three lines with an empty second line.